# Developing a standalone application using Java

Tags: java, swing

I want to build an application using Java related frameworks but i do not have an idea to start it.

The description is as follows:

I need to fetch flat files containing legacy data from UI and then send it to the structured database for storing the structured data. It is basically a conversion of legacy data into structured form.

In this above process i want to display the error logs on the UI itself.

How could i achieve this functionality and which framework or technology will be better to use? Is it good to use Swing?

Comment: which frameworks you should use is depending on which ones you know. If you have no idea how to start, I assume you are not very experienced in Java yet. Start with a good analysis and the back-end. Keep the back-end code separated from the front-end.
Write your code in modules, and keep your classes both organized and easy to read.

Comment: Yes, looks like a fairly simple UI, you can start with Java Swing, Probably showing a progress bar that displays the number of records processed and a list of error messages.

Comment: This question is too vague for StackOverflow. You need to ask something more specific/technical for which there is a definite answer. This is why you are getting those downvotes. For example start working on the application and ask many small questions about specific issues you encounter.

Comment: If you want to be smart, you should just use SPRING BOOT in a console application so that you can interact with the database through spring-data-jpa.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a simple console application. If you don't need a GUI don't use one. Otherwise Swing is fine.

You can use Spring and Hibernate to handle the database connectivity.

Logging would be via Log4j which can output to Console.

It seems you have a lot of studying to do to get started.